# Is Dressing Up As A Hindu Deity Prohibited At All?

Tags: goddess, bhakti

Outside of theater piece, television/film for the public, festival re-enactment, RamLeela, outside of these obviously religious presentations, is there any Hindu text that says we shouldn’t dress up as a Hindu deity ?

I’ve seen people told by elders and priests on two separate occasions that it’s not ok outside of a religious festival.

So like parents dressing kids as Krishn on Janmashtami, women dressing as Goddess during Navratri, or a religious presentation like a theater presentation of Ramayan or Mahabharat, these are fine & ok.

A Hindu mytho classical dance composition, a Hindu mytho theater piece, film, television show, is a religious re-enactment so is considered ok too.

But outside of such stuffs, people were told it’s not ok.

I follow a lot of Devi bhakti accounts, and many people dress and do their makeup as Kali. They go all out with the makeup, jewelry, costume, props. They deliver lines from epics, act out situations, and I guess in general sort of channel the Goddess. Then they upload the clips onto their socials & followers like me see them.

Do our shastras say this is disrespectful or wrong in any way ?

(I’d love to dress as Kali too but feel nervous that it could be against the rules for a Hindu devotee in some way.)

Do our scriptures say we shouldn’t dress as a Devi/Devta ?

Edit : I know this could get closed as an opinion based question but wasn’t really asking for opinions, more wondering if Hindu texts say anything about this, or if Hindu temples would have strict rules about it.

Comment: We were sternly rebuked and told not to do this. But I wonder if there is really any rule against it ?

Comment: as a kid, I saw lot of 'jhaakis' around. Basically people dressed up as Gods and even Rakshas and doing a kinda parade

Comment: @Rambhakt You know what I was thinking today, I’d really like to see amazing incredibly well-made series of both Ramayan & Mahabharath. Directed by some Indian film school graduate who was heavily influenced by Chris Nolan & Francis Ford Coppola type of directors. No cheesy songs, no ridiculous costumes. Just total unknown actors with loads of talent. Terrific musical score. Just really magnificent, brooding, serious, kind of majestic. I feel like these epics deserve that kind of storytelling. If I was billionaire I’d hire some production company to make that. It would be so awesome 

Comment: Some stuff have been announced. [Disney+hotstar's Mahabharat](https://www.hindustantimes.com/entertainment/web-series/new-mahabharat-series-announced-at-d23-expo-to-release-on-disney-hotstar-check-out-concept-art-101662783883755.html) , 3 Ramayans which include Adipurush, Sita with Kangana playing titular role, another with Ranbir, Hritik as Ram, Ravan respectively. Adipurush teaser have taught me to keep expectations in pataal lok. Rajamouli has said he will make Mahabharat with new actors towards the end of his career. @devibhakt

Comment: still it is best to keep expectations low as Adipurush teaser has taught use. What you have described will take decades to come because of attitude here in India.

Comment: @Rambhakt I think that’s the case. “Adipurush teaser have taught me to keep expectations in pataal lok.” <——  Hahaha!:D  Yeah, zactly  So, yeah, we’ll see, how those newer productions shape up. I watch & rewatch Hindu mytho shows, from the old stuff made decades ago, to whatever is being made these days. I’m happy to see well made scenes, good dialogue delivery, good actors in these huge roles. Which sometimes happens in not great mytho series too. I like the stories & characters so much, so even when the shows aren’t superb or whatever, just seeing them gives me great happiness 